# CUBLAS - is matrix-element exponentiation possible?

Tags: matrix, cuda, cublas

I'm using CUBLAS (Cuda Blas libraries) for matrix operations.

Is possible to use CUBLAS to achieve the exponentiation/root mean square of a matrix items?

I mean, having the 2x2 matrix

```
1 4
9 16
```

What I want is a function to elevate to a given value e.g. 2

```
1 16
81 256
```

and calculating the root mean square e.g.

```
1 2
3 4
```

Is this possible with CUBLAS? I can't find a function suitable to this goal, but I'll ask here first to begin coding my own kernel.

Comment: Note, this isn't matrix exponentiation (nor is it root mean square).  You're simply performing scalar operations on the individual elements.

Comment: Excuse for the mistake, yes I need to perform such operations

Comment: I've updated the question title accordingly.

Comment: You're just taking the root of each element in your example, which is not the root-mean-square of your elements. Well, in fact the root-mean-square of a single number is just its absolute value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So this may well be something you *do* have to implement yourself, because the library won't do it for you.  (There's probably some way to implement it some of it in terms of BLAS level 3 routines - certainly the squaring of the matrix elements - but it would involve expensive and otherwise unnecessary matrix-vector multiplications.   And I still don't know how you'd do the squareroot operation).   The reason is that these operations aren't really linear-algebra procedures; taking the square root of each matrix element doesn't really correspond to any fundamental linear algebra operation.

The good news is that these elementwise operations are very simple to implement in CUDA.  Again, there are lots of tuning options one could play with for best performance, but one can get started fairly easily.

As with the matrix addition operations, you'll be treating the NxM matricies here as (N*M)-length vectors; the structure of the matrix doesn't matter for these elementwise operations.   So you'll be passing in a pointer to the first element of the matrix and treating it as a single list of N*M numbers.  (I'm going to assume you're using `float`s here, as you were talking about `SGEMM` and `SAXPY` earlier.)

The kernel, the actual bit of CUDA code which implements the operation, is quite simple.  For now, each thread will compute the square (or squareroot) of one array element.  (Whether this is optimal or not for performance is something you could test).  So the kernels would look like the following.  I'm assuming you're doing something like B_ij = (A_ij)^2; if you wanted to do the operation inplace, eg A_ij = (A_ij)^2, you could do that, too:

```
__global__ void squareElements(float *a, float *b, int N) {
    /* which element does this compute? */
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    /* if valid, squre the array element */
    if (tid < N) 
            b[tid] = (a[tid]*a[tid]);
}

__global__ void sqrtElements(float *a, float *b, int N) {
    /* which element does this compute? */
    int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    /* if valid, sqrt the array element */
    if (tid < N) 
            b[tid] = sqrt(a[tid]);   /* or sqrtf() */
}
```

Note that if you're ok with very slightly increased error, the 'sqrtf()' function which has maximum error of 3 ulp (units in the last place) is significantly faster.

How you call these kernels will depend on the order in which you're doing things.  If you've already made some CUBLAS calls on these matricies, you'll want to use them on the arrays which are already in GPU memory.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan, you wrote even too much to help me. 

I'm still wondering how to implement some slightly subtle details (number of blocks/threads, how to maximize coalescence, ecc..) but I'll give a try and have some tests running first.

I'll post another question if I have any other doubt

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: User @solvingpuzzles currectly pointed out that `block_id` which I had in the above code should of course be `blockIdx.x`; I have no idea why I put `block_id` in there.